# How do I extract the "href" attribute from an XML "link" tag using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am stumped as to how I can extract the "href" attribute from the "link" tag from this bit of XML using my PHP parsing script.  If it helps at all, I am trying to extract the URL of a particular post from a GetSatisfaction API feed.

Here is an example a node from the XML file:

```
<entry>
  <link rel="something" href="http://...url_I_need" type="text/html"/>

  <title type="html">...title here...</title>
  <content type="html">
  ...content here...
  </content>
</entry>
```

And here is the data gathering portion of my PHP XML parsing script:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('http://api.getsatisfaction.com/companies/issuetrak/topics?sort=recently_active&limit=7');
$arrFeeds = array();
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('entry') as $node) {
 $title = $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
 //I need to just store the link->href value to $link below
 //$link = ???;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to extract that "href" attribute?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `getElementsByTagName('title')` when you want an attribute of `<link>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about [`DOMElement::getAttribute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php)?

```
$href = $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use:

```
$link = $node->attributes['href'];
```

But I prefere use simpleXml;

http://www.php.net/simpleXml

Comment: I think SimpleXML uses a selfmade XML-parser instead of a common library like libxml. I feel very unsafe using it.

Comment: I used getAttribute() instead of attributes()...I got all error. You helped me :D Thanks